# Python convert object to time in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am struggling to convert an object type to datetime. It's a column from a dataframe that has values in format dd.mm.yyyy (e.g. 13.03.2021).

dataframe: df

column: time

values in format: dd.mm.yyyy

desired output: dd-mm-yyyy

Below are the options which I already tried, but it does not work out.

```
df['time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['time'].astype(str))

df['time'] = datetime.strptime(df['time'], '%d-%m-%Y').date()

df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%d-%m-%Y')

df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], dayfirst=True)
```

Any ideas? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Have you tried, `df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], infer_datetime_format=True)`?

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%d.%m.%Y')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using datetime and `strptime` along with `strftime` would suffice the need.
Hope the below code helps.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

data = ['13.03.2021','23.03.2021']
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['time'])

new_date = []
for x in df['time']:
   new_date.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(str(x), '%d.%m.%Y').strftime('%d-%m-%y'))
df = pd.DataFrame(new_date,columns=['time'])
print(df)
```

**Output**

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtfMe.jpg)

Comment: Why do I get error message "time data ' 13.03.2021' does not match format '%d.%m.%Y' (match)"?

Answer (score 1):

To get the format you want in the database, you can convert the time string to a datetime object, then format it to the string you want:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df=pd.DataFrame(['01.02.2001','02.03.2002'],columns=['time'])
>>> df
         time       # dtype=object
0  01.02.2001
1  02.03.2002
>>> df.time = pd.to_datetime(df.time,format='%d.%m.%Y')
>>> df
        time        # dtype=datetime64
0 2001-02-01
1 2002-03-02
>>> df.time = df.time.dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
>>> df
         time       # dtype=object
0  01-02-2001
1  02-03-2002
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
d = {
    "time":['13.03.2021', '12.03.2021','11.03.2021']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], infer_datetime_format=True)
for i in range(0,len(df)):
  x=(str(df['time'][i])[:10])
  df['time'][i]=datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%d-%m-%y')
```

Output -

```
    time
0   13-03-21
1   12-03-21
2   11-03-21
```